# How to run a progress bar (that gets % increments every x seconds) in parallel to an ajax call?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, modularity

This is part of my object:

```
const qwData = {

    // Initialize functions
    init: function() {
        this.cacheDom();
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Cache vars 
    cacheDom: function() {
        this.dataDisplayed  = false;
        this.countUsers     = <?php echo $_SESSION['all_users_count_real']; ?>;
        this.$form          = $('#frm_reportit');
        this.start_date     = this.$form[0][9].value;
        this.end_date       = this.$form[0][10].value;
        this.dateCount      = this.countDays(this.start_date, this.end_date);
        this.show           = document.querySelector('#btn-show');
        this.downloadBtn    = document.querySelector('#download_summary_button');
        this.$dataContainer = $('#qw-data-container');
        this.$qwTable       = $('#qwtable');
        this.$qwTbody       = this.$qwTable.find('tbody');
        this.qwChart        = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main-chart'));
        this.progressBar    = document.querySelector('.progress-bar');
        Object.defineProperty(this, "progress", {
            get: () => {
               return this.progressPrecent || 0;
            },
            set: (value) => {

                if(value != this.progressPrecent){
                  this.setProgressBarValue(value);
                  this.qwChartProgress = this.returnNumWithPrecent(value);
                }
            }
        });
        this.qwChartProgress= this.progress;
    },
    // Bind click events (or any events..)
    bindEvents: function() {

        var that = this;

        // On click "Show" BTN
        this.show.onclick = this.sendData.bind(this);

        // On Change inputs
        this.$form.change(function(){
            that.updateDatesInputs(this);
        });

    },

sendData: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let that = this;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/test/ajax.php?module=test_module",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
                start_ts: that.start_date,
                stop_ts: that.end_date, 
                submitted: true
        },
        beforeSend: function() {

            // Show Chart Loading 
            that.qwChart.showLoading({ 
                color: '#00b0f0', 
                // text: that.returnNumWithPrecent(that.progress)
                text: that.qwChartProgress
            });

            // If data div isn't displayed
            if (!that.dataDisplayed) {
                // Show divs loading
                that.showMainDiv();
            } else {
                that.$qwTbody.slideUp('fast');
                that.$qwTbody.html('');
            }
        },
        complete: function(){


            let timer = setInterval(that.incrementProgress, 500);

        },
        success: function(result){

            // Set progressbar to 100%
            that.setProgressBarTo100();

            // Show Download Button
            that.downloadBtn.style.display = 'inline-block';

            // Insert Chart Data
            that.insertChartData(result);

            // Insert Table Data
            that.insertTableData(result);
        }
    });

    that.dataDisplayed = true;
},
// Insert Data to Table
incrementProgress: function(){
    this.progress += 10;
},
..... 
.............
....................
```

I am trying to get `this.progress` to get incremented every 0.5 seconds by 10% (by adding 10 to `this.progress`). 
I'm not sure where to do that, and how. I tried adding it to `beforeSend:` and `complete:` but all i get is a 0% progress bar without any time delays. How is the proper way to write this?

Comment: way to achieve this is to put your setInterval outside of the ajax call, and to clear it on completion. Not sure about the usefulness of the whole thing though.

Comment: I tried putting it right after the row `let that = this;` before the ajax. didn't work. @VladimirM

Comment: Oh yea... I've missed one spot there. you are using "this" in the increamentProgress. Should you be using "that"?

Comment: No, because it's `this` is pointing directly to the object and in ajax i use `that` because when you get inside $.ajax, `this` becomes the ajax request. Double checked with console.log() right now.. `this` is fine.

Comment: are you sure that timeout event handler keeps the context? you are not passing it as a function(){  that.incrementProgress() } but as a function reference.

Comment: I console.log("test")-ed and it did run every 0.5s in the console. :0 
So I am doing it right and there's something else?

Comment: it does run every 0.5 seconds, no doubt about that. But what does it increment?

Comment: @VladimirM I added the top part of my code for more clearance (`this.progress` definition too)... Please review :)

Comment: Please test with let timer = setInterval(that.incrementProgress.bind(that), 500);   Cheers.

Comment: sorry @VladimirM I was wrong about the "this" before, if consoled.log all the functions of the page and not the object. So using bind does point now in `this`. when i `console.log(this.progress);` inside    `incrementProgress: function(){` i get 0 logs every 0.5s

Comment: @RickSanchez please test my comment answer, should work ?

Comment: @IamSilviu I did, works the same with `this` and `that`.

Comment: then do qwData.progress += 10. or setInterval(that.incrementProgress.bind(qwData), 500). Also check that that == qwData (maybe the way you call sendData is on different context)

Comment: this is how i call `sendData`: `this.show.onclick = this.sendData.bind(this);`

Comment: @VladimirM just updating... i started reading this now: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Might be the problem..

Answer (score 1):

```
Object.defineProperty(this, "progress", {
            get: () => {
               return this.progressPrecent || 0;
            },
            set: (value) => {

                if(value != this.progressPrecent){
                  this.progressPrecent = value;
                  this.setProgressBarValue(value);
                  this.qwChartProgress = this.returnNumWithPrecent(value);
                }
            }
        });
```

This was the problem `this.progressPrecent = value;`

It was always 0 because when getting the value it didn't set it in `this.progressPrecent`.

Answer (score 0):

You still have the same problem. Here is the digest of it:

My test definition:

```
var test = {
    progress: 0,
    increment:function(){
        this.progress = this.progress+10;
    }
}
```

test is { progress: 0, increment: function }

```
test.progress();
```

test is { progress: 10, increment: function }

```
setTimeout(test.increment, 20)
```

test is { progress: 10, increment: function } since method is passed by reference!!!

```
setTimeout( function(){test.increment() }, 20)
```

test is { progress: 20, increment: function } since the context is preserved!!!

So, even if your timer is correctly started, it will increment progress in whatever context, which is not the intended one.

Comment: is `Object.defineProperty(this, "progress", {...` is the same as: 
`this.progress = {
 progress: 0,
    get: function(){
       return this.progressPrecent || 0;
    },
    set: function(value) {
        if(value != this.progressPrecent){
          this.setProgressBarValue(value);
          this.qwChartProgress = this.returnNumWithPrecent(value);
        }
 },
    increment:function(){
        this.progress = this.progress+10;
    }
};`

Comment: or you mean to create the progress bar separate to qwData

Comment: What I mean,  is that in your code you have at least one point that will fail, if everything else is correct. And that is your timeout event handler.  Move this line  let timer = setInterval( function(){that.incrementProgress();}, 500); after that=this, at least to see if anything is happening.

Comment: moving `let timer = setInterval( function(){that.incrementProgress();}, 500); ` after `that=this;` increases the bar to 10% once and does nothing more than that. I added a `console.log(this.progress);` after `this.progress += 10;` and got a 0 output every 0.5s `277 0 qws:563`

Comment: I assume that you are updating this.progressPrecent inside this.setProgressBarValue(value);